# Enabling the second dropdown only when the first dropdown has a value selected with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I write a jQuery function that enables the second dropdown only if a value is selected on the first dropdown? By default the page is loaded with the value that is stored on database. If value is null then it shows the option "Select a owner/co-owner"

```
<select name="owner">
    <option value="">Select an Owner</option>
    <option value="1">John</option>
    <option value="2">Jack</option>
    <option value="3">Mary</option>
</select> 

<select name="co-owner">
    <option value="">Select an Co-Owner</option>
    <option value="1">Bill</option>
    <option value="2">Mark</option>
    <option value="3">Larry</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really quite simply. All you need is a generic function that has the logic to decide whether to disable and reset the co-owner dropdown, and then run this function when the owner dropdown has its value changed, or if the page is first loaded.

The disable/enable logic is really simply. We simply store the owner check as a boolean in a variable called `hasOwner`. If `hasOwner` is true, `!hasOwner` evaluates to `false` and we can use in `.prop('disabled', !hasOwner)` to toggle the disabled status.

The disable and reset behaviour is simply triggered by calling `.prop('disabled', <boolean>)` and setting an empty value using `.val('')`. The latter is more of a usability issue, because you do not want the old selection state to persist when it is disabled and re-enabled later.

I typically favour this approach because you can always change the decision logic in the generic function, without needing to worry about updating any duplicated code elsewhere—especially if the behaviour is also intended on pageload.

p/s: I have added IDs to your select elements simply for the convenience of selection. If you want to select by the `name` attribute, just use `$('select[name="owner"]')` for example.

```js
$(function() {

  // Generic logic
  var toggleDropdown = function(owner) {
    // hasOwner is a boolean store
    var hasOwner = typeof owner !== typeof undefined && owner;

    // Use boolean to decide whether to disable/enable co-owner field
    $('#co-owner').prop('disabled', !hasOwner).val('');
  }

  // Trigger logic when #owner is updated
  $('#owner').on('change', function() {
    toggleDropdown($(this).val());
  });
  
  // Trigger logic on DOM ready
  toggleDropdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="owner" id="owner">
    <option value ="">Select an Owner</option>
    <option value ="1">John</option>
    <option value ="2">Jack</option>
    <option value ="3">Mary</option>
</select>

<select name="co-owner" id="co-owner">
    <option value ="">Select an Co-Owner</option>
    <option value ="1">Bill</option>
    <option value ="2">Mark</option>
    <option value ="3">Larry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you modify the code to only disable the second dropdown not hiding? Thank you

Comment: I am still having some errors in my page. Starting from line " } else { "..... is all comment out. I don't see it why. I am using a <script type="text/javascript"> </script> tag to put your code inside and is located on the same page with the html. Can it work from here or I must put it on a .js page?

Comment: Is all commented out? Are you using some kind of syntax highlighting, perhaps? I can't see why the code is invalid though, it should work. But you can of course try putting it in a JS file and load it, and see if that works for you.

Comment: Yes, I was able to make this work too. When I put the code on a .js file worked good. I am working on coldfusion file so I don't know if that impacted or not.

Answer (score 2):

You just need three jQuery functions: [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change) to detect the event, [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) to retrieve the chosen value and [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to enabled/disable the related dropdown. Try this:

```js
$('.owner').change(function() {
  $('.co-owner').prop('disabled', $(this).val().trim() == '');
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="owner" class="owner">
    <option value="">Select an Owner</option>
    <option value="1">John</option>
    <option value="2">Jack</option>
    <option value="3">Mary</option>
</select> 

<select name="co-owner" class="co-owner">
    <option value="">Select an Co-Owner</option>
    <option value="1">Bill</option>
    <option value="2">Mark</option>
    <option value="3">Larry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I added the jQuery function but the second dropdown is still active no matter what option is selected on the first dropdown!

Comment: Have you added the classes I used to select the elements?

Comment: OK, now I see where the problem is. When the page is first loaded even if the owner has no value the second dropdown is enabled. However if I change the first dropdown to some other value and then back to no value then the second dropdown is deactivated. How can I make to work on the page load too?

Comment: I got it. If anyone needs this for future reference I added this piece of code:

$(document).ready(function() {
        var ownerValue =  $('.owner').val();
        if(ownerValue == '') $('.co-owner').prop('disabled', $(this).val().trim() == '');
    });

Comment: Yes, that is true I used you logic to make it work also on page load.

Comment: Yes, but the logic I posted also works on page load - note that I'm triggering a `change()` event immediately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144085/discussion-between-doarna-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a class.

```
$('.owner-class').on('change', function() {
  if(this.value==='') {
       $('.co-owner-class').hide();
  }else{
       $('.co-owner-class').show();
 }

})
```

With you code changing to

```
<select class="owner-class" name="owner">
    <option value="">Select an Owner</option>
    <option value="1">John</option>
    <option value="2">Jack</option>
    <option value="3">Mary</option>
</select> 

<select "co-owner-class" name="co-owner">
    <option value="">Select an Co-Owner</option>
    <option value="1">Bill</option>
    <option value="2">Mark</option>
    <option value="3">Larry</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {

  // Generic logic
  var toggleDropdown = function(owner) {
    // hasOwner is a boolean store
    var hasOwner = typeof owner !== typeof undefined && owner;

    // Use boolean to decide whether to disable/enable co-owner field
    $('#co-owner').prop('disabled', !hasOwner).val('');
  }

  // Trigger logic when #owner is updated
  $('#owner').on('change', function() {
    toggleDropdown($(this).val());
  });
  
  // Trigger logic on DOM ready
  toggleDropdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="owner" id="owner">
    <option value ="">Select an Owner</option>
    <option value ="1">John</option>
    <option value ="2">Jack</option>
    <option value ="3">Mary</option>
</select>

<select name="co-owner" id="co-owner">
    <option value ="">Select an Co-Owner</option>
    <option value ="1">Bill</option>
    <option value ="2">Mark</option>
    <option value ="3">Larry</option>
</select>
```

Comment: let is suppose, I want these functionality only for jack and mary, without remove the value of John.